# Eclipse 4 RCP CSS Templates

Tags: css, eclipse, e4

I´m developing an Eclipse 4 RCP Application.

When I start the Application, it looks like a really old one. 
As I know, it is possible to style the E4 Application via CSS, so I looked for a Standard Eclipse 4 CSS Template or so (to get the look and feel of Eclipse 4), but I was not able to find one.

So is there maybe a way to get it out of my Eclipse installation?

Comment: The existing stylesheets are in `plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.xxxx/css` in the Eclipse install.